# C# use split to separate two parts of string

Tags: c#, excel

I have the following text in an Excel spreadsheet cell:

```
"Calories (kcal) "
```

(minus quotes).

I can get the value of the cell into my code:

```
string nutrientLabel = dataRow[0].ToString().Trim();
```

I'm new to C# and need help in separating the "Calories" and "(kcal)" to to different variables that I can upload into my online system. I need the result to be two strings:

```
nutrientLabel = Calories
nutrientUOM = kcal
```

I've googled the hell out of this and found out how to make it work to separate them and display into `Console.WriteLine` but I need the values actually out to 2 variables.

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in nutrientsdataTable.Rows)
{
    string nutrientLabel = dataRow[0].ToString().Trim();
}

char[] paraSeparator = new char[] { '(', ')' };
string[] result;

Console.WriteLine("=======================================");

Console.WriteLine("Para separated strings :\n");

result = nutrientLabel.Split(paraSeparator,
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string str in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: Well you _could_ do `nutrientLabel = result[0]; nutrientUOM = result[1]` but it's not clear why you need separate variables instead of just accessing the array by index.

Answer (score 1):

```
string [] s = dataRow[0].ToString().Split(' ');
nutrientLabel  = s[0];
nutrientUOM  = s[1].Replace(")","").Replace("(","");
```

Comment: You can't have an empty character literal in your replace. If you switch to the the `string, string` overload you should be fine. Also, you don't need to call `Trim()` since you're only accessing elements 0 and 1 (the empty element 2 doesn't matter).

Comment: or `s[1].Trim('(', ')')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex for this:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(?<calories>\d+)\s\((?<kcal>\d+)\)");
```

Which essentially says:

1. Match at least one number and store it in the group 'calories'
2. Match a space and an opening parenthesis
3. Match at least one number and store it in the group 'kcal'
4. Match a closing parenthesis

Then we can extract the results using the named groups:

```
var sampleInput = "15 (35)";
var match = reg.Match(sampleInput);
var calories = match.Groups["calories"];
var kcal = match.Groups["kcal"];
```

Note that `calories` and `kcal` are still *strings* here, you'll need to parse them into an integer (or decimal)